# Constructing callback url for Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to construct a callback url that will get called once a payment succeeds. This 'Success URL' is called on the payment providers end, so I can therefore not supply any headers etc. for the request, only a URL.

[Parse.com getting data from callback URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644003/parse-com-getting-data-from-callback-url) in this question it seems that it is possible to construct a url with the app ID and REST API Key in the actual URL, but I can't figure out how.

I've tried the approach the person in the above question has done, but with no luck. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Is this a bad approach? Is there any alternatives?